# Table of Objects in Lua

Tags: object, oop, lua, instance

I'm attempting to create a Lua object like this

```
Block = {x = 0, y = 0, color = "red"}

function Block:new (x, y, color)
   block = {}
   setmetatable(block, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.x = x
   self.y = y
   self.color = color
   return block
end
```

Then putting several instances of this object into a table in a separate file

```
blocks = {}
table.insert(blocks, Block:new(0, 0, 'red'))
table.insert(blocks, Block:new(2, 0, 'blue'))
table.insert(blocks, Block:new(1, 1, 'green'))

for i,v in ipairs(blocks) do
    print(i,v.x, v.y, v.color)
end
```

But my output is

```
1   1   1   green
2   1   1   green
3   1   1   green
```

How can I get these objects to retain their own instance in the table?

Comment: Inside `Block:new` function body `self` is a class, `block` is an instance.  So, replace `self.x = x` with `block.x = x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
Block = {x = 0, y = 0, color = "red"}

function Block:new (x, y, color)
   block = {}
   setmetatable(block, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.x = x
   self.y = y
   self.color = color
   return block
end
```

The first problem that causes all your instances to be the same is that you did not make `block` local to the function. Instead each call to `Block.new` operates on the same global variable. So every time you call it you overwrite the result of the previous call.

The second problem is that you do not modify your instance but the class itself. As your instances don't have `x`, `y` and `color` you fall back to Block's value due to __index referring to Block

self refers to the table `Block` as `function Block:new(x, y, color)` is equivalent to `function Block.new(self, x, y, color)` and your function call `Block:new(0, 0, 'red')` is equivalent to `Block.new(Block, 0, 0, 'red')`

So you try to create an instance of the `Block` class named `block`. If you want to change that instances properties you must use `block.x = x` instead of `self.x = x` as you otherwise will alter `Block` which then would reflect on all instances.

```
Block = {x = 0, y = 0, color = "red"}

function Block:new (x, y, color)
   local block = {}
   setmetatable(block, self)
   self.__index = self
   block.x = x
   block.y = y
   block.color = color
   return block
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting x,y,color on `block` rather then `self`

```lua
function Block:new (x, y, color)
   block = {}
   setmetatable(block, {__index = self})
   block.x = x
   block.y = y
   block.color = color
   return block
end
```